# Can I wrap a javascript event in a jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('a.one').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        function test(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.test { font-weight: bold; }
        body { font-family:sans-serif; background-color:#AAAAAA;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="one" href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <br/>
    <a class="two" href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onclick='test(event)'>stack overflow</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The test-function does not work as it stands now, since a regular javascript event doesn't support the jQuery event preventDefault-function. Is there some way to wrap a regular javascript event in a jQuery event so that I can use e.g. preventDefault?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
function test(e) {
    $.Event(e).preventDefault();
}
```

[Event object](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event)

Comment: This does give you access to some methods, but is not a "normal" JQuery event...  For instance, you cannot use:  $.Event(e).which

Comment: $.Event(e) does implement preventDefault, stopPropagation, and stopImmediatePropagation. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L664

Answer (score 5):

I've found the best way to wrap a native event in a jQuery event is with `fix`:

```
event = $.event.fix(event);
```

Please note, this function is not part of the public API (although it really should be).

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the fact that you're passing event in with onclick='test(event)'. I think onclick='test' is enough. I could be wrong though.

Comment: It's fine. It picks up the `event` global on IE and the `event` argument on other browser and passes it to the function so that it doesn't have to do the usual `if (!e) e= window.event` IE workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (see Darin's answer). You could also work around IE's lack of preventDefault instead (which is essentially what jQuery is doing):

```
if ('preventDefault' in event)
    e.preventDefault();
else
    e.returnValue= false;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just want to execute the javascript - and not redirect - when clicking the href use "return false" in your click function. For example:

```
$(function(){
        $('a.one').click(function(event){
                var condition = confirm('Do you want to redirect to ...?');
                return condition == true;
        });
});
```

If you never want the link to redirect use 'javascript:void(0);' as href attribute, all browsers will still render it as a link instead of an anchor (some IE version do this).